# Increasing separation between body and footnotes when using KOMA

Tags: fonts, footnotes, koma-script, debugging

I have tried

```
\skip\footins=2\baselineskip
```

and it works; but now on page 4 my page number is set in a different font (apparently Latin Modern) than my main font!  What must I add or change to avoid that?  (I'm using LuaLaTex.)

PS.  It has proven difficult to reproduce this in a minimal example.  The problem disappears if I remove or change certain parts of my text, but I haven't managed to isolate it.  It is surprising to me that *anything* in my text (not pertaining to the page number) should be able to influence the page number.  Filling with lipsum does not produce the problem.  Any guesses or debugging tips appreciated.

PS II.  The problem *seems* to depend on the koma class option `footinclude=true`, so I'm disabling that for now.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.